# Material Design - set input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I have edit form, made with material design and I set input with jquery

> $("#item").val('value')

But then it has [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAOFP.png) effect. Until I edit it with a keyboard, js from material design "thinks" there is no text in inputs.

I tried triggering events like .change(), .keyup() or keypress(), it didn't work.

Thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: Can you prepare demo on jsfiddle or etc?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvZQbj

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKJbLG is working for now.

Comment: If it's working I will write as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKJbLG)

script:

```
$("#sample1").val('TEST').parent('.mdl-textfield').addClass('is-dirty').removeClass('is-invalid');
```

Comment: that focus was good, but the underline should be blue so user knows it's valid input